# Go 'back' after clicking link to anchor (within same document/website)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, html

Navigating longer documents online, e.g. Wikipedia, document references are usually marked up with hyperlinks to an HTML anchor.

Using Chrome and Windows, how can I click that anchor, read what is there, and then (actual question:) go back to where I was (ideally with a simple keyboard shortcut), circumventing the need to take an explicit mental note of the scrollbar/where I am in the document?

`CTRL+Z` seems to have worked to my recollection, but apparently doesn't on all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the *Back* button or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.